# Is there any Symfony 2 book coming out soon?

Tags: symfony

Currently there's no Symfony2 book but the Symfony 2 documentation. Anyone knows if there's a Symfony2 book coming out soon?

Answer (score 5):

Well, the official [book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) is really a *book*. A guy once told us on the `#symfony` channel he printed it and it took ~400 pages, IIRC.

I learned Symfony by this official book and with the help of community on the IRC channel.

And I once met another guy on the channel, who asked several questions on the framework, stating that he was writing a Symfony book. But I'm not sure, whether he was referring to a “real” book we will someday be able buy on Amazon.com or to just another web book.

What I didn't like is that the guy was asking so basic questions, that I noticed he's not a real practitioner who works in the trenches and uses the framework for doing real projects. I mean, even if that book comes out, I doubt it will be as real world and of such high quality as the official one, which is written by core Symfony developers.

Answer (score 0):

The core book written by the original creators of Symfony 2 is sufficient in itself to provide you an expert training in Symfony 2. So, I don't think you need any other book to learn symfony.